# How to pass raw resource id data from activity to service?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was asked to display list of songs, playing, pausing, and stopping only using Android core components.

I've managed to display songs list. Also I have implemented play/pause/stop functionality but the problem is that I can only play hardcoded music files.

This is my onCreate function from the Service class:

```
override fun onCreate() { 
     super.onCreate() 
     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sampl) 
     mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { 
         stopSelf() 
     } 
 }
```

Basically, my goal is to be able to change that R.raw.sampl with any other file from my raw folder that user chooses from the fragment.

This is how I am playing music in Fragment

```
binding.btnPlay.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MusicService::class.java)
            intent.action = MusicService.ACTION_PLAY
            requireActivity().startService(intent)
        }
```

Comment: All songs are located at raw folder?

Comment: yes. they are all in raw folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun listRaw() {
    val fields: Array<Field> = R.raw::class.java.fields
    for (count in fields.indices) {
        val resourceID = fields[count].getInt(fields[count])
    }
}
```

The above code can be used to list all the files from the raw folder and use the resource id to play them inside the media player.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceID)
```

resourceID will be same as `R.raw.sampl`

For Activity to Service communication, it is advised to use Binder.
Watch this [video](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/concurrent-programming-with-android-threads-workers-and-kotlin-coroutines/started-services-and-background-processing-limits?autoplay=true&resume=false) for getting a better understanding on service.

MyService class

```
class MyService : Service() {

    private val binder = MyServiceBinder()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return binder
    }

    fun playMusic(ab: Int) {
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,ab)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }

    inner class MyServiceBinder : Binder(){
        fun getService() = this@MyService
    }
}
```

And in the activity

```
private lateinit var myService: MyService
private val connection = object : ServiceConnection{
    override fun onServiceConnected(p0: ComponentName?, p1: IBinder?) {
        val binder = p1 as MyService.MyServiceBinder
        myService = binder.getService()
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {

    }

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Intent(this,MyService::class.java).also{
        bindService(it,connection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        startService(it)
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unbindService(connection)
}
```

And on button click or whenever you want to play music. Instead of R.raw.ab use the resourceID

```
if (::myService.isInitialized) {
                myService.playMusic(R.raw.ab)
            }
```

Comment: i don't understand how do i pass the music file selected by the user from the fragment? i did it with putExtra() but there is fileNotFoundException. or am I getting whole thing wrong? :)

Comment: i've slightly edited my question

Comment: How do you handle activity to service communication?

Comment: here is the gist (https://gist.github.com/mcicishvilii/a5fc0157bacac51ef97197fe677acba2) of my fragment

Comment: why you are using database ?

Comment: it's in my assignment

Comment: I have updated my answer, use as per your usage

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your raw resource id to your service via intent:

```
binding.btnPlay.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MusicService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("playSong", R.raw.sampl)
    intent.action = MusicService.ACTION_PLAY
    requireActivity().startService(intent)
}
```

Then, get your resource id in the service:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
   super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

   if (intent != null && intent.extras != null) {
      val songResId = intent.getIntExtra("playSong", -1)
    
      if (songResId != -1) {
         //play song
      }
```

Comment: do i put the service code in onCreate or in onStartCommand? it's kinda tricky to wrap my head around. when i run as you told, i get null in getExtra

Comment: I've updated my answer. Pls check it out.